# Custom variable in Rails view filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

By default, Rails can find views with the format, locale and template language in the filename (so I can create `index.de.json.erb`)

Is it possible to add another, custom parameter to the view's filename?

I would like to pass the current subdomain, so `http://foo.example.com/` would render `index.foo.html.erb`, and `http://bar.example.com/` would render `index.bar.html.erb` (both of them with `index.html.erb` fallback).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The resolving pattern that is used to look up views can only contain variables that are registered with the `ActionView::LookupContext` class. The first step is therefore to register a new variable (`subdomain`) with the `LookupContext` class. You should do this in an initializer:

```
ActionView::LookupContext.register_detail(:subdomain) do
  ['default_subdomain']
end
```

Now the `LookupContext` knows about the `subdomain`, it can be included in the resolving pattern. For more detail about changing the resolving pattern, see the [`ActionView::FileSystemResolver` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/FileSystemResolver.html), but essentially you should include the following, also in an initializer:

```
ActionController::Base.view_paths = ActionView::FileSystemResolver.new(
  Rails.root.join('app', 'views'),
  ':prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:subdomain,}{.:formats,}{.:handlers,}'
)
```

This pattern is eventually passed to [`Dir.glob`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob) (after the `:*` variables have been replaced). The glob pattern `{.:subdomain,}` means *“either `.:subdomain` or nothing”*, which provides the fallback to a view file with no subdomain if the file with a subdomain isn't found.

The final step is to update your `ApplicationController` to pass the subdomain to the `LookupContext`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def details_for_lookup
    {:subdomain => [request.subdomain]}
  end
end
```

(This answer was mostly figured out by reading source code, some of these features aren't documented. It was tested with Rails 3.2.5)

Comment: Glad I could help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If an answer solves your problem, you should mark it as accepted, more info on how and why here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a custom handler here. You don't perform some prepossessing of your templates, but you just need your templates to become domain-specific.

I would consider making something like this:

```
# in ApplicationController:
  before_filter :set_view_paths

  def set_view_paths
    self.class.view_paths = Rails.root.join('app', 'views', controller_name, request.subdomain)
  end
```

Then you have to put your templates for the `foo` domain into `foo` folders of each `views/controller_name` path.

Also check [`append/prepend_view_path` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/ViewPaths/ClassMethods.html) to allow defaults in case of absence of a domain view.